# how to create a filter system?

Tags: php, html

i have a database like this 
prod_id prod_name catogory_1 catogory_2 catogary_3
now i want place my filter like this

```
<slect id="filter for cat 1">
<option vlaue="all">all</option>
<option vlaue="caps">Caps</option>
<option vlaue="shoose">shoose</option>
<option vlaue="cloths">cloths</option>
<option vlaue="bags">bags</option>
</slect>

<slect id="filter for cat 2">
<option vlaue="all">all</option>
<option vlaue="mens">mans</option>
<option vlaue="womens">wonens</option>
<option vlaue="babys">babys</option>
</slect>

<slect id="filter for cat 3">
<option vlaue="all">all</option>
<option vlaue="large">Larg</option>
<option vlaue="midum">midum</option>
<option vlaue="small">small</option>
</slect>

<div id="display_prod_list">
here goes the list
</div>
```

my function

```
<?php
function display_product() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `pord_id` AS `id`, `prod_name` AS `name`,
        `catogory_1` AS `catogory_1`, `catogory_2` AS `catogory_2`,
        `catogory_3` AS `catogory_3` FROM `porducts`");
$products = array();
while(($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))!== false) {
$products[] = $rows;

}
return $pruducts;
}
?>
```

this function returns all products i want to change this function to return only filtered products
how can i do that? please help me. can i do this with php or i have to use jquery or something. please 
tell me the best way to filter my products thanks

Comment: "WHERE" didn't the OP try....?

Comment: hey guys i am new on this so its seems like a fulish question to u. sorry for that. tell me the where condition for all if i pass the value of 3 select filds to my function and put where condition "where cat_1=$cat-1 && cat_2= $cat-2 && cat_3=$cat-3" but what is the where condition for all. this is my first time so i have no idea how can make a filter system.

Comment: First, you should get rid of your typos in your code or else nothing will run properly. ;) (`catogory` and `catogary`, `pord`, `vlaue`, `slect` etc.)

Comment: It was a subtle hint at what to look at.  If you know you should use a where condition in the SQL statement then please mention that in the question, generally the more information you provide in the question the better.

Comment: i just want to if user select bag small baby i want dispaly only samall baby bag not the hole product list thats all i want to do and that select id and option values r not real that is for example only can somebody help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is about what you asking for, but hope it helps.

Use a WHERE clause on your MySQL query, for example:

```
SELECT `pord_id` AS `id`, `prod_name` AS `name`,
        `catogory_1` AS `catogory_1`, `catogory_2` AS `catogory_2`,
        `catogory_3` AS `catogory_3` 
  FROM `porducts`
WHERE catogory_1 = 'caps' AND catagory_2 = 'babys';
```

You could build your query condition in this way:

```
$conditions = array();
$condition_string = '';

if ($catagory_1 != 'all') { $conditions[] = "catagory_1 = $catagory_1 "; }
if ($catagory_2 != 'all') { $conditions[] = "catagory_2 = $catagory_2 "; }
if ($catagory_3 != 'all') { $conditions[] = "catagory_3 = $catagory_3 "; }

if ($conditions) { $condition_string = ' WHERE '. implode($conditions, ' AND '); }

$sql = 
"SELECT `pord_id` AS `id`, `prod_name` AS `name`,
            `catogory_1` AS `catogory_1`, `catogory_2` AS `catogory_2`,
            `catogory_3` AS `catogory_3` 
 FROM `porducts` $condition_string ";
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer i know i have to use where but what is the where condition for all. guess i have a production like catogory_1 = bag, catogory_2 = babys and catogory_3= small. i want to show that item when user select bags, babys, all. in this case my query look like this ("///codes WHERE  catogory_1 = 'bags' AND catogory_2 = 'babys' AND catogory_3= 'all'");  query returns false because that item catogory_3 is small not all. this is my problem

Comment: what you gotta do, is no include that condition when the value is all (or 0). i'm editing, check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

**Just PHP**

A standard HTML form that sumbits to the php script which executes query based on the filter values when the submit button is pressed.

The use the [SQL WHERE clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to narrow down your results to products that match the criteria.

eg. `WHERE catogory_1 = 'caps' AND catagory_2 = 'babys';`

You will also need to put some logic in the php to prevent you from querying for a category when the filter value is 'all', as you can effectively ignore those categories.

Then output your results.

**PHP & jQuery**

You could use jQuery to populate the products part of the page with only the products that match the category filters when a filter is changed rather than reloading the page.  A ajax request is made to the a php script that queries based on the current filters.

For example, all products are shown when your page loads at first then the "filter for category 1" is changed to "caps", using jQuery to detect a [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on the filter an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to a php script that would run the following query.

```
SELECT `pord_id` AS `id`, `prod_name` AS `name`,
        `catogory_1` AS `catogory_1`, `catogory_2` AS `catogory_2`,
        `catogory_3` AS `catogory_3` 
FROM `porducts`
WHERE catogory_1 = 'caps';
```

Then build your HTML based on the results and this is sent back as the ajax response and you should use it to replace the current HTML for the products.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but what is that logic code which ignore the where clause fo the catogory value is all. look my comment on first answer and really thanks for ur answer and time.